# dropdown element arrow move upside down when clicked

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I don't know if theirs an attribute or something for this arrow on a select element but basically when you toggle the drop down the arrow rotates 180 degrees if i can find an attribute for the arrow then i won't have a problem doing it. Any suggestions.

```
<select class = "two">
 <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value='' class = "ddowns_vari" value = " 2. design"> 2. design</option>
</select>
 <div class = "selected_content2">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
```

you can also find the demo site here
http://79.170.40.182/kingsley-test.co.uk/kingsley%209.9.2016/kingsley-new/contingency.php

Comment: Just FYI, a URL to localhost is not something that other people can go to. Try making a https://jsfiddle.net/ to show a demo

Comment: hahaha i did know this promise, http://79.170.40.182/kingsley-test.co.uk/kingsley%209.9.2016/kingsley-new/contingency.php

Answer (score 0):

That's not really the right way to use a select element and unfortunately as it is a browser object there is little you can do to modify it.

You would be better off with something like this

```
<div>
  <span>Select this</span>
  <div>Content here</div>
</div>

div {width: 200px;}
span {display: block;}
span::after {content:"V"; float: right;}
span:hover::after {transform: rotate(180deg); cursor: pointer;}
```

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/QKapyA

Obviously changing the V for a suitable arrow icon or graphic and adding some jQuery to show the div below.